# Connection of magento 2 site with akeneo pim installed in localhost using akeneo connector

Tags: magento2, api, magento-community

Environment:
Magento: 2.3.4.
Akeneo PIM: Vr 4 (community )
[image]

Hi!
I have downloaded akeneo community pim using docker. It's installed in my mac and can be accessed at localhost:8080.
I have also installed an official akeneo connector in my Magento 2 site. Now to connect Magento 2 site with pim i have generated the credentials from the akeneo PIM portal. There are 5 components of the information required for configuration;

Akeneo base URL: **Using localhost URL**
Akeneo User id: Provided by akeneo pim site 
Akeneo User PWD: Provided by akeneo pim site 
Akeneo API Client Id: Provided by akeneo pim site 
Akeneo API Client secret: Provided by akeneo pim site

But when I submit the information by click on the TEST button, I get the following error:

"cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

I understand that Magento 2 is not able to connect to the pim installed in my localhost. My question is which akeneo base URL to use to connect the Magento site to my pim

thanks
Harish

[image]

Comment: You just cannot connect form the remote server to your localhost this way. To do this you should turn your computer into a webserver and open traffic to external connections.
Take a look here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364406/access-to-a-site-on-localhost-from-remote
https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/
https://medium.com/botfuel/how-to-expose-a-local-development-server-to-the-internet-c31532d741cc

Comment: Hi! i did realise that my entire approach to installing PIM on localhost was wrong as even after using a local server - it becomes difficult to connect akeneo/PIM to magento 2 site installed on web. I tried using ngrok to get an external ip but every time i made an attempt to connect PIM to magento 2 site- my site crashed (basically cloudfare was timing out the connection). I now would try and use pimcore installed on a webserver as the hardware requirements of akeneo/pim are phenomenal and my magento site setup simply cannot support it now